# it’s every bit as possible to loop reliably - don't really get this

Tags: meaning

> While I applaud your work ethic, you do realize that it’s **every bit as possible** to loop reliably and predictably without all that formal initializating and updating stuff ? Besides, I often repeat code in situations where there isn’t a need to initialize anything, and the updating takes place right there in the action code. So I’m content to do without the formality and just focus on the looping.

I can't make sense of the part in a bold type.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is [General Reference](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/every-bit)

Comment: On the contrary, I don't think the meaning of the phrase is necessarily obvious to an English language learner.  It also requires understanding that *possible* is converted from a binary to scalar attribute, and that *every bit as* is an emphatic form.  It's true that there are definitions for *every bit as* in a small number of learner's dictionaries, but I don't think they're really adequate to the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that it is wholly, completely, and entirely possible to loop reliably and predictably without formal initialization for whatever coding concept is being discussed. In English, *bit* is a small piece/part of something, so when you say "Every bit of/as" you are usually referring to all aspects of a concept.

For example, if whatever concept being discussed didn't always reliably and predictably loop, then it would only be marginally possible or "just a little bit possible". "Only a little bit" can be used if not referring to the entirety of a concept.

Since it is always possible, then it is entirely, or every little bit/aspect about it is possible.